# How to specify a path for HAML views?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

In my Sinatra web app I'm doing this:

```
get '/' do
  haml :index, layout: :layout
end
```

I want Haml to load my `index.haml` and `layout.haml` files from a specific directory, not the default one. How to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `:views` configuration:

```
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "my_templates") }

get '/' do
  haml :index, layout: :layout
end
```

If you want to put your templates in a directory that is not a top level directory, then you need to do this:

```
set :views, Proc.new{ File.join root, "my_templates", "haml_templates" }
```

Then sinatra will look for the views in `your_app/my_templates/haml_templates`